# How to call a task separately in gradle

Tags: java, gradle, build

My build.gradle file looks like below.

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    maven {
      mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {    
  compile "commons-logging:commons-logging:1.0.4",
          "commons-codec:commons-codec:1.3"      
 } 

jar {
    manifest{            
            attributes ("Product-Name" : project.name, "${manifestSectionName}")
            attributes ("Product-Display-Name" : project.description, "${manifestSectionName}")
            }                                
    }

task build1  {
 sourceSets {
   main {
      java {
         srcDirs = ['src/java/com/abc/xyz/dir1']
      }
    }   
  }
  buildDir = 'op'
  jar{
  archiveName = 'build1.jar'
  }
}

task build2  {
 sourceSets {
   main {
      java {
         srcDirs = ['src/java/com/abc/xyz/dir2']
      }
    }   
  }
  buildDir = 'op'
  jar{
  archiveName = 'build2.jar'
  }
}
```

So now I want to call individual task to build individual jar, the way we invoke individual targets in Ant.

So when I am calling it like : gw clean build build2
its building build2.jar in correct way, but when I am running it like:           gw clean build build1, its still building build2.jar only.

I am very new to gradle, so not sure about this.

Its still building build2.jar only, I am not sure why its happening .. can someone help me here?

Note that both tasks are independent of each other.

Answer (score 0):

When configuring build1 and build2, you're configuring the unique, shared, main sourceSet and the unique, shared, jar task. Since build2 is configured after build1, it overrides the configuration set by build1.

What you want instead is two additional tasks in the build, which both create a jar with a different content:

```
task build1(type: Jar) {
    dependsOn classes
    archiveName = 'build1.jar'
    from(sourceSets.main.output) {
        include '**/package1/**/*'
    }
}

task build2(type: Jar) {
    dependsOn classes
    archiveName = 'build2.jar'
    from(sourceSets.main.output) {
        include '**/package2/**/*'
    }
}
```

But that looks to me like bad design. If you want to generate different jars, then you should probably have several subprojects, all using the java plugin and not needing any configuration.

Comment: Can you elaborate this further ? from ... {
        ...
    }

Comment: I agree with you, but in that case I will be having many subprojects which I dont want, so I want to have just 1 build.gradle having different tasks.

Comment: Elaborate on what? Have you read https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html?

Comment: in from I mentioned path to java file, now its building build1.jar, but inside it its packing the java file, which should be ideally class file. It should compile it first.

Comment: The from shouldn't point to the sources, but to the compiled classes directory. Something like SourceSets.main.output (see https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSet.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSet:output)

Comment: Yes, I got it, so before it I need to write a task to compile these files.

Comment: The java plugin already adds that task. All you need to do is call it before your buildX tasks, or, better, make sure your buildX tasks depend on it: `dependsOn classes`

Comment: If possible can you write complete code snippet, because I am getting little bit confused here, where exactly I need to mention the source java code directory then ?

Comment: Done. You don't need to mention the java source directory anywhere.

Comment: Last question... include '*/package1/**/' ..here what exactly I need to mention at package1 because my complete dir path to java file is "src/java/com/abc/xyz/dir2/converter.java"

Comment: You're not adding Java files to your jar. You're adding class files, compiled by the previous gradle tasks, from the directory containing the compiled package tree. So if you want to include everything under the package `com.foo.bar`, you would use `include 'com/foo/bar/**/*'`

Comment: Sorry, but this approach is not working, its building the jar, but there is no class file inside that.

Comment: What is your gradle code, what are the packages of your classes? This code works fine. I tested it.